# Why do service accounts appear with the CLI gcloud and not in the IAM Cloud Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

`gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=<MY_PROJECT>` shows a number of service accounts that simply do not appear in the [IAM Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=myproject).

Why is this?

I made sure that it is the same project; that there is no second page in the Console listing; and that some of the same service accounts *do* appear in the Console.

The missing ones were created to report on a Kubernetes cluster and take the form

```
reporter-<CLUSTER-NAME>@<MY_PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Are you authenticating using the same credentials, for both, web console and cli? What do you get when you run `gcloud auth list`?

Comment: The link you provided it's meant to show the roles associated with the accounts. Could you try looking at (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/service-accounts) by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#listing_service_accounts) to see if they match the ones from gcloud command? If they don't please share what do you see to help you further.

Comment: @ParthMehta -- yes, same credentials.  `gcloud auth list` just gives my one account

Comment: @Happy-Monad Why don't some  service accounts appear in that first page -- while some do? That page is titled "Permissions - View by members", so I would expect all members to appear, with their permissions.

Comment: Maybe it is because you didn't grant them any permissions. Could you try going to the service account tab and giving to one of the accounts some permission to see if then they appear? I'll update the answer once this gets confirmed or If I find on my own why this happens .

Comment: I tried adding a role to a service account that did not appear in the main IAM page. However, under the Add dialog, I got "Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account or Google Apps account." But anyway, I think we can accept  your point  as correct, since this page https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts says "f the service account isn't already on the members list [on the main IAM page], it doesn't have any roles assigned to it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link provided it's meant to show the roles associated with the accounts. To list the accounts in your project you need to go to the Service Accounts tab of IAM, you may use this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/service-accounts) or follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#listing_service_accounts).

---

Editing the question to include the information posted in comments, therefore I will set it as community wiki:

@joshua-fox: [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) states that accounts without permissions won't show in IAM page.

@john-hanley: Accounts automatically created by Google won't show under IAM but will show under "Service Accounts". If you modify these accounts permissions then they will appear on IAM. Accounts might be created when certain services are enabled (ex: App Engine).

Comment: Google Cloud Service Accounts created on your behalf by Google Cloud do not show up under IAM members. They do show up under Service Accounts. If you modify one of the Google accounts by modifying roles, they will show up under IAM members. There are many service accounts with Google assigned roles. An example is the `Service Agent` type. Google assigned service accounts are often created when a service is enabled.